# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException using Entity Framework connection string with Azure SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I have hosted my web application which is using database first using Entity Framework `.EDMX`. I have the following connection string.

```
<add name="Entities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/FdaSecOpsModel.csdl|res://*/FdaSecOpsModel.ssdl|res://*/FdaSecOpsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=....database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=DEV01;integrated security=True;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The error I get is:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong here? Previously the connection string worked with SQL Server.

**Updated**: I removed `Integrated Security = true;` and now I'm getting the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

After making changes as per the last comment but getting error as :

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

Thanks

Comment: "Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server." and your connection string indicates "integrated security" which indicates windows login, so should work if you remote that.

Comment: You should remove `integrated security=True;` or set it to false when you provide user id and password.

Comment: I removed integrated security, but getting another error. I have updated above.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use integrated security and use as login the server admin you specified when you created the Azure SQL Database logical server or create a [new database user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins#non-administrator-users). Your connection string should look like below:

```
<add name="MyEntities"
connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.Model.csdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.ssdl|
res://*/App_Code.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string='Data Source=my.database.windows.net;
Initial Catalog=myTest_DB;User ID=***;Password=***; 
MultipleActiveResultSets=False'"  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Error: "System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'." probably means your connection string is invalid.

Comment: Thank you. But getting System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource error